# vue2: is possible to pass multiple props to component?

Tags: vuejs2

i find no documentation online or examples, but which is the correct way to pass multiple props to component?

here what i have tried:

**in HTML**

```
<component:prop1="data1" :prop2="data2"></component>
```

**in component.js**

```
props: ['prop1','prop2'],
```

but obiusly don't work...

Comment: Can you share more code? As maybe the root cause is another problem since the code you show here should be working.

Comment: @kevlai22 thanks! is enough to know that is possible, and this is a correct way

Comment: Here is an example I made for a tutorial, hope it can help. https://codepen.io/kevlai22/pen/LLJZrp

Comment: well, thanks also if is not exactly what i was trying to do, is more related to parent to child props

Answer (score 31):

despite this been a little old, I'd like to contribute.
If you want to pass a bunch of propeties "at once" together you could use "v-bind"

Let's say your component has a bunch of props:

```
props: ['age', 'year', 'date']
```

Instead the regular way below:

```
<MyAwesomeComponent :age="age" :year='year' :date='today' />
```

It's also possible to do:

```
<MyAwesomeComponent v-bind="groupedProps" />
```

been "groupedProps" the following object:

```
groupedProps: {age:134, year:2153, today: new Date()}
```

> ...**v-bind="groupedProps"**...

the behavior is described in the vue docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object)

Answer (score 11):

You can pass multiple props to components like this.
In parent component:

```html
 <template>
   <div id="app">
     <child-component :propA=propa :propB=propb></child-component2>
   </div>
 </template>
 
 <script>
 import ChildComponent from './components/comp2'
 export default {
   name: 'app',
   components: {
     ChildComponent
   },
   data () {
     return {
       propa : 65,
       propb : 'Nitin'
     }
   }
 }
 </script>
 
 <style></style>
```

In child component:

```html
 <template>
   <div>
     {{propA}}
     {{propB}}
   </div>
 </template>
 
 <script>
 export default {
   props: {
     propA: Number,
     propB: String
   }
 
 }
 </script>
 
 <style lang="css">
 </style>
```

Reference:
[Vue Prop-Validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation)

EDIT:
More info and example references can be found at:
[Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)

Comment: Actually no @thenm, you should update your answer with this link: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props , there are many other examples in the documentation that use multiple props.

Comment: What is the difference between the syntax above `:propName=foo` and the examples on vuejs.org `v-bind:propName="foo"`

Comment: @Half_Duplex Nothing at all. :propName is just shorthand for v-bind:propName.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to ask this question

In `parent.js`

```
props: ['prop1','prop2'],
```

and you want to bind some properties to a child component using properties of parent's.

```
child.js
props: ['prop11', 'prop21']
```

I just want to confirm the above question is right or not. If yes, you should do the beneath

```
parent.js
data() {
   return {
     prop11: this.prop1,
     prop12: this.prop2
   }
}

and bind it
<child :prop1:"prop11" :prop2:"prop21"/>
```